# multiply two pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas dataframes:

df1

```
   id        type    NY    PA    MD
0  90  superurban   0.1   0.1  0.08
1  88       urban   0.1  0.08  0.08
2  75    suburban  0.06  0.04  0.04
3  60       rural  0.04  0.02  0.02
```

df2

```
  name  item
0   NY  1000
1   PA   500
2   MD   250
```

How can I multiple "item" values in df2 with df1 float values according to state abbreviations? The output should be:

```
   id  type         NY    PA   MD
0  90  superurban   100   50   20
1  88  urban        100   40   20
2  75  suburban      60   20   10
3  60  rural         40   10    5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

we can do it this way:

```
In [112]: d1[['NY','PA','MD']] *= d2.set_index('name')['item']

In [113]: d1
Out[113]:
   id        type     NY    PA    MD
0  90  superurban  100.0  50.0  20.0
1  88       urban  100.0  40.0  20.0
2  75    suburban   60.0  20.0  10.0
3  60       rural   40.0  10.0   5.0
```

Or [much better variant from @JohnGalt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45716976/multiply-two-pandas-dataframes/45717274#comment78392608_45717274):

```
In [118]: d1[d2['name']] *= d2.set_index('name')['item']

In [119]: d1
Out[119]:
   id        type     NY    PA    MD
0  90  superurban  100.0  50.0  20.0
1  88       urban  100.0  40.0  20.0
2  75    suburban   60.0  20.0  10.0
3  60       rural   40.0  10.0   5.0
```

Comment: @ScottBoston, yeah, it would be interesting to know... ;-)

Comment: Very elegant. You could `d1[d2['name']] *= d2.set_index('name')['item']` perhaps?

Comment: thank you! indeed, these are very elegant solutions!

Answer (score 2):

Or you can using `mul` ;

```
df1[['NY','PA','MD']]=(df1[['NY','PA','MD']].T.reset_index().drop('index',1)).mul(df2.item,axis='index').T

Out[888]: 
   id        type     NY    PA    MD
0  90  superurban  100.0  50.0  20.0
1  88       urban  100.0  40.0  20.0
2  75    suburban   60.0  20.0  10.0
3  60       rural   40.0  10.0   5.0
```

Comment: OP, It is better you accept @MaxU 's answer, His answer is more neat , if you like my answer, you can upvote it

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I actually posted a small variant of the problem. I actually have a dataframe of all 50 states so it is a bit of a pain to type out all of them.

Comment: @arqchicago same solution here, change`['NY','PA','MD']` to `d2['name']`